# PhpStorm & SVN: How to fetch remote copy and override the local copy

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm, zend-studio

In Zend Studio there is a command "Replace (e.g. file/dir) with latest from repository", which fetch SVN remote copy of file/dir and overrides the local copy.

How can I do the same in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch last remote copy with "Revert".
Keyboard: Choose file -> Ctrl+Alt+Z 
Mouse: Choose file -> right click -> Subversion -> Revert